# Regex - accept letter, digit, underscore, but don't accept speific string

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I am trying to make a regular expression which should accept letter, digit, underscore but shouldn't accept insensitive input `www`.

That means that the input can be `wwwblabla` or `blablawww` or any word containing `www` but it can'be only `www`. Is there any posibility to make a regex like this?

I've got the expression for digit, letter, undeserscore, but I don't know how to connect the `www` condition: `/(^[a-zA-Z0-9_+]$/`

Comment: Why is it a requirement to use a regex for this and not do it some other way?

Comment: `str.match(/^\w$/) && str != 'www'`

Comment: @NPE Because I am using a validator and I must adding a regex. It's the only way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To quantify a character class you put quantifier outside of it and if you want to capture something you should close opening parenthesis.

With a negative lookahead you can exclude `www` from matches:

```
^(?!www$)\w+$
```

- `\w` => `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/zZUMrn/1)

Comment: Negative lookahead matching on `www` will prevent matches against any words ending in `www`.

Comment: @lordcheeto There are two anchors involved. So what you said never happens.

Comment: Look at live demo.

Comment: @revo It works very well. I tried to make a negative lookhead, but it didn't work because it was `^(?!www)\w+$`. I didn't put the dollar sign inside paranthesis.

Comment: @ValentinEmilCudelcu Yes, that's an important thing to consider.

Comment: @revo Didn't know that :)) So in 30-45 minutes I wasn't able to create this regex. Thanks.

Comment: @revo I wasn't considering it with that constraint, I was doing word boundaries and global matches, sorry. +1

Comment: No problem. @lordcheeto

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to achieve this in one regular expression. I suggest instead that you use a whitelist and blacklist concept.

As others have mentioned, `\w` is equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. You might also want to match against word boundary (`\b`) instead of start and end of line.

The whitelist/blacklist can be single strings or regular expressions, depending on your requirements.

Pseudocode:

```
if regex(string, pattern = whitelist) and string != blacklist
```

Note that if the regex doesn't match, it will [short circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), so it won't check whether the blacklist matches. If you expect that the blacklist will match more often than the whitelist, you'll want to swap the two.

**Edit:** If you're matching against a single word per line, the negative lookahead works. Looks like what you were doing in your expression, so disregard this.

Comment: Your assumptions on *not being possible to do it in one regex* is wrong.